# HTML5 Canvas Question | Click Tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, drawing

Recently, I have started dabbling with HTML5 and the mighty canvas. However, I am trying to accomplish something and I am not sure what the best way would be to handle it.

I am trying to make a randomly generated set of buildings with windows, as you can see in the following example that uses divs:

[**Example Using Divs**](http://jsfiddle.net/rionmonster/jNb7Z/5/)

The issue that I am coming up with is that I want to be able to randomly generate images/content in the windows of these buildings, and be able to easily capture when a window is clicked, but I am not sure how to go about handling it using the canvas.

**Example Building:**

```
function Building()
{
     this.floors  = Math.floor((Math.random()+1)*7); //Number of Floors
     this.windows = Math.floor((Math.random()+1)*3); //Windows per Floor
     this.height  = (this.floors*12);                //1px window padding 
     this.width   = (this.windows*12);               //1px window padding

     //Do I need to build an array with all of my windows and their locations
     //to determine if a click occurs?
}
```

**Example Window:**

```
function Window(x,y)
{
     this.x = x;    //X Coordinate 
     this.y = y;    //Y Coordinate
     this.color =   //Random color from a range
     this.hasPerson //Determines if a person in is the window
     this.hasObject //Determines if an object is in the window
}
```

**Summary: I am trying to generate random buildings with windows, however I am unsure how to go about building them, displaying them and tracking window locations using the canvas.**

### UPDATE:

I was finally able to get the buildings to generate as I was looking for, however now all I need to do is generate the windows within the buildings and keep track of their locations.

**[Building Generation Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rionmonster/wXN9M/)**

Comment: I'd be glad to try to elaborate as much as possible or answer any questions if it would help.

Comment: Wouldnt you consider a table for this? Because in essence, you just want some rows and columns right? Tables handle onclick events just fine, there's no need to worry about that.

Comment: @TJ, I know there are several ways to accomplish this. I just wanted to get more familiar with working with the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess if you are drawing the window, you already have the function to create their canvas path.
 So you can apply the [isPointInPath](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-ispointinpath) function on all window you have to determine if the user clicked on a window.

```
 canvasContext.beginPath()
 {
    (functions corresponding to your window path)
 }
canvasContext.closePath()
var isInWindow = canvasContext.isInPath(clicPosX,clicPosY);
```

Comment: Do I get it right that you have to redraw the canvas on each click (which is OK in games) to use `isPointInPath`?

Comment: No, you just need to recreate the path using the beginPath and closePath functions. Creating a path does not mean redraw the windows.

Answer (score 1):

Draw your squares using [`fillRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Rectangles), store their north-western point coordinates into an array. You'll also need these rectangles' dimensions, but since they are all equal squares — no need to store them in the array.

Then add a click listener to the canvas element, in which detect the pointer's position via [`pageX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.pageX)/[`pageY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.pagey) minus the position of the canvas element.

Then on each click traverse the array of rectangles and see if they contain the pointer's coordinates:

```
if (((pageX > rectX && pageX < rectX + rectWidth) || (pageX < rectX && pageX > rectX + rectWidth))) &&
    ((pageY > rectY && pageY < rectY + rectHeight) || (pageY < rectY && pageY > rectY + rectHeight))) { 
    /* clicked on a window */
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/katspaugh/UtxEx/).

Comment: This gets very, very tricky when the user starts scrolling the page, or even zooming can affect this.

Comment: @TJHeuvel, yes, getting the relative position of the pointer can be tricky, but that's another topic on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

Actualy you have to check where mouse is clicked, and if it's in window, then call some function. And yes, you will need to have array, of locations.

Take a look [here](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1935)